# Using Maven resource plugin on dependecy jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

Maven has resource plugin that can delimiter a character that can tell it in pom file , for example in the blow config define it that replace "#" character.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/filtered-resources/scripts</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/assemble/resources/scripts</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>#</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but it work on files that directly exists in my project , i want to do the same job in a jar file , i have a jar file that exists some java script plugins and i want add it to my project but i need replace somethings on it . 
and the dependency is something like this :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>sample.javascript</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsLibrary/artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A jar file is an already compressed and packaged file which can't be filtered anymore. If you like to filter things you need to unpack the jar file...

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to unpack your jar. You can use this plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html

2) change

```
   <directory>src/assemble/resources/scripts</directory>
```

to the directory  with unpacked jar